# Shap library can't be installed during ci-cd pipeline at gitlab

Tags: python-3.x, docker, gitlab, egg, shap

I have a problem with installing shap library during pipeline at gitlab. If i have in my .gitlab-ci.yml following line:

```
pip install shap==0.34.0
```

I get the following during gitlab job:

```
Collecting shap==0.34.0
Downloading shap-0.34.0.tar.gz (264 kB)
ERROR: No .egg-info directory found in /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-2c2ywcxu
```

I use gitlab runner 13.5.0 and cannot reproduce this error at gitlab-runner host machine with pure docker - it installs successfully then (using the same docker image). I tried with another shap versions and with uprading pip and setuptools - it doesn't help.